# Modify the html code of site with DOM and CURL

Tags: php, dom, curl

I'm trying to modify content of my local site, so I recuperate the content of the site with CURL PHP then i parsing it with DOM and i change the html code to optimise it.for example i change tag  to  or in this example ,i change the position of script javascript in the end . no i need to applicate this modification in the site so how can i use curl or onther solution if existe to upload the new content of the site.

```
<?php
$URLs = "http://localhost/...";// url of site 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URLs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$source = curl_exec($ch);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();   
 $dom->recover = true;
 $dom->substituteEntities = true;
 $xhtml = (preg_match('/XHTML/', $source)) ? true : false;
        switch ($xhtml) {
            case true:
                $dom->loadXML($source);
                break;
            case false:
                $dom->loadHTML($source);
                break;
        }
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$body = @$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        foreach (@$dom->getElementsByTagName('head') as $head) {
            foreach (@$head->childNodes as $node) {
                if ($node instanceof DOMComment) {
                    if (preg_match('/<script/i', $node->nodeValue)){
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;
                         $moveme[] = $node;
                    unset($src);
                    }
                }
                if ($node->nodeName == 'script' && $node->attributes->getNamedItem('type')->nodeValue == 'text/javascript') {
                    if (@$src = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue) {
                                        } else {
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;

                    }
                     $moveme[] = $node;
                    unset($src);
                }                
            }
        }
          foreach ($moveme as $moveit) {
            $body->appendChild($moveit->cloneNode(true));
            $moveit->parentNode->removeChild($moveit);
        } 
         $body = $xhtml ? $dom->saveXML() : $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could store some of your site-content in a temporary folder( including a timestamp ) and use that for the site. every xxx minutes or so, you could run your script and write the contents of the output to that temp-folder. your script needs to be placed on the webserver for that.
i also found a site, that explains what i wrote in more detail:
http://www.snipe.net/2009/03/quick-and-dirty-php-caching/

 beware, that tutorial is called quick-and-dirty for a reason :)

Comment: thank you. But I did not understand who can i load the new content (or the new html code) in the site,can you please explain me more

Comment: add the line 
file_put_contents( 'filename.html', $body ); 
to your script - the script needs to be installed on the same webserver - you could use a "hidden" url( security-by-obscurity ) and place that script there - once you activate the script, the whole page will be changed OR start the script from the command-line( eg from cron ) and update the file with that

Comment: I try but no result , I developed a component for optimization site so I test my component (my script) in joomla

Comment: so .. the script is working and you want to upload the code on the website. is that code static ... or is the website something dynamic
( eg with php ).
if its dynamic( with php ), you cannot use the means, that i wrote before. that could be accomplished with an output-buffer instead of curl_exec.
if its a static page and you want that optimization done only once,
you need to upload your script there ... otherwise you need to include some ftp-way to upload your optimized script. if the script is uploaded, you just need to rewrite the file, that is called in the url

Comment: I think that I should explain what I do exactly because I don’t understand you very well.
First,I’m a student and my PFE study is to develop a tool for the analysis of web sites and a suitable component for any CMS website optimization.
I try to develop a component like component and plugin  joomla but the difference is that my component is developed in PHP (so I do not use the JFactory .... From joomla)

Comment: the component will be installed in CMS sites where the site administrator wants to optimize eg javascript, I propose some optimization: the position javascript, minify js files .. And run my script. I need that the purpose of my component done some optimization to the site automatically without the site administrator applies itself

Comment: hmmm ... i dont know the internals of joomla, but that script would work only when applied to "static" html, without any calls to joomla.